# Android - How to create an image selector

Tags: android, image, selector

In my app i need to use something that will let the user select an image from device.
How is the simple way to do this?

Remembering that i'll use that image after selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the user going to select the image from gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use thi code to select image from Gallery

```
galleryPic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            Util.DogDye = false;
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                    1);

        }
    });
```

and after this add one new method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    switch (requestCode) {

    case 1:
        if (data != null) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(path);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap btemp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,
                        options);
          /// use btemp Image file 

        }
        break;
    }

}


   public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following which opens the gallery and lets user pick an image.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

switch(requestCode) { 
case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    }
}
```

}

'selectedImage' is the selected image, so you can use it in the rest of your application now.